# How to convert a word document (.docx or .rtf) to responsive html for mobile and web view

Tags: html, docx

I am working on an Ionic app using Angular and Firebase.
I need to display multiple 50-page word documents accessed through links on the app menu.
The documents contain important charts, graphs, and illustrations that need to be displayed.
I could use angular-document-viewer, but since the doc is created on a pc, the scaling would be off.

**How can I convert the .docx documents to responsive HTML, keeping the charts, graphs, and illustrations intact and legible on all screen sizes**?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the charts and illustrations but it seems to be pretty extensive. Plus it seems that you can apply custom styles.

[Docx.js](https://docx.js.org/#/usage/document)

Works with npm.

Comment: Not really what I am trying to do. I just want to know the best way to make a word document readable in an app

Comment: I don't think I get what you're trying to do I'm sorry. I'm not sure that parsing a docx could generate responsive HTML with charts etc. Imho, you should convert the docx as a PDF, but that doesn't respond to your original demand.

Comment: I ended up saving it as HTML and used HTMLTidy https://www.html-tidy.org/documentation/  to get rid of the extra tags and added styles to make charts legible. not the fastest solution, but the best one I found.